# Why does k8s by design uses 3 ports for NodePort's services instead of just 2

Tags: kubernetes, containers, kubectl, ports, orchestration

I am seeing that to create a nodePort service using a yaml manifest there are three port parameters to enter: port, targetport and NodePort.

To give an example, I have this hypothethical manifest:

Now I know the port's mapping doesn't make good sense for a real-life case, but just take the ports as they are mapped for this example's purposes:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nodeportdeployment5
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: whatever
  ports:
    - name: someContainer-listening-on-111
      port: 49699
      targetPort: 111
      nodePort: 30007
    - name: someContainer-listening-on-5432
      port: 5432
      targetPort: 5432
      nodePort: 30008
```

So you see, I have two containers in the pods tagged `whatever`. One listens on 111 and the other one on 5432.

Now, my understanding and research so far tells me that (and please correct me if I am wrong)

1. A request towards the cluster's I.P to port 30007 will be received just there
2. From port 30007 on the cluster, it will re-direct it to the service which is listening on port 49699
3. From port 49699 of the service,  it will redirect it to the pod, into the pod's port 111

So my question is, why is step 2 necessary? Why does it goes: `cluster->service->pod` , why not just `cluster->pod` . I mean, why not something like this

1. A request towards the cluster's I.P to port 30007 will be received just there
2. The cluster receives it and simply forwards it right there to a pod's port 111

So why is it necessary that what the cluster's receives needs to be passed onto a service that again pass it to another pod's service? Instead of the cluster just saying `whatever I get on port 30007 I will send it some pod's 111`. Why is the service in between the cluster's IP and the pod's IP?

My guess is because the service's functionality is to manage to which of all the possible pods it should redirect the request to, because there can be multiple pods from the same deployment if `replicas>1`, and also, because pod's I.Ps can change with each re-deployment. But is that the reason? And are there other reasons?